# php update mysql statement not working but same query works via phpmyadmin sql menu

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I am running a script to update a MySQL table, and I have been echoing the update statement to help troubleshoot why the update statement was not working.  When I copy and paste the echoed query for the mysql update into the SQL menu in phpmyadmin, it works perfectly, but when I run the script the update query does not execute.  I know I have successfully connected to the database.  Does anyone know why an echoed version of the update statement copy and pasted into the sql tab of phpmyadmin would execute successfully, but not the actual query that is supposed to be executed the line before the echoed statement?  Here is my php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$user = 'tunemashercom';
$pass = 'password';
$host = 'tunemashercom.ipagemysql.com';
$db_name = 'user_library';
@ $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);  

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.';
    exit;
}

$oldsongs = $_POST['oldsongs'];
$newsongs = $_POST['newsongs'];
$count = count($newsongs);
$count2 = count($oldsongs);
echo "COUNT 1: ".$count." - COUNT 2: ".$count2."<br />";
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
    $newtitle = $newsongs[$i]["song"];
    echo $newtitle." - ";
    if($newtitle == ""){
        echo "NO NEW TAGS<br />";
    }
    else{
        $title = $oldsongs[$i]["title"];
        echo $title."<br />";
        $artist = $oldsongs[$i]["artist"];
        $album = $oldsongs[$i]["album"];
        $newartist = $newsongs[$i]["artist"];
        $newalbum = $newsongs[$i]["album"];
        $mbid = $newsongs[$i]["mbid"];          
        $insert = "UPDATE collection SET song='".$newtitle."', artist='".$newartist."', album='".$newalbum."', gille_id='".$mbid."' WHERE song='".$title."' AND artist='".$artist."' AND album='".$album."'";
        $results = $db->query($insert);         
        echo $insert."<br />";      
    }
}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error does it show when you try the update from the PHP side of things? Need a little more info here.

Comment: There where no errors from the PHP side of things.  The script runs through perfectly and echoes the update statement for every iteration of the for loop, but when I check the database, none of the queries were actually executed.  But when I copy and paste the statement that was echoed (the same update query) into the SQL form in phpmyadmin, the update query executes exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error it's difficult to know what the problem it, however, from my personal experience when that's happened to me on UPDATE queries it was always because I wrapped an ID with quotes.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related to quotes. While typing single quotes are 'sumthng' but while executing update query, we need `sumthng`. I hope this works. I faced the same problem and it was solved using the quotes copied from phpmyadmi directly.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the phpmyAdmin is the same database as the php code so "tunemashercom.ipagemysql.com"

Check to make sure that the database that you are (running the echo query) using phpmyAdmin is the same as the one what you are connecting to with your PHP code.

For example that you are connecting to phpmyAdmin from your local machine and your php code is connecting to your database at hosting server.

Comment: The user pointed out phpMyAdmin works perfectly, but his code doesn't. I downvoted because it seems a rushed answer to me without any additional explanation. If you expand the answer I am more than happy to remove the downvote. Thanks.